# Can't execute correctly Active record in ruby threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

How to execute correctly a simple ActiveRecord query within threads in ruby?

here is the code without threads, a simple action.

```
  def no
    1000.times do |i|
      Post.create(name: 'fabian')
    end
  end
```

Now with threads i think that probably should be:

```
def yes
    1000.times do |i|
      Thread.new do
          Post.create(name: 'fabian')
      end
    end
  end
```

But i'm getting some rollback results in log

[image]

I've also tried with following code:

```
def yes

    threads = []
    1000.times do |i|
      threads << Thread.new do
        begin
          Post.create(name: 'fabian')
        ensure
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection
        end
      end
    end

    threads.map(&:join)
  end
```

With same results.

This is just an example, in the future I want to use this in more complex code.

Comment: Did you try creating posts with a bang? that will reveal the error or validation  for rollback `Post.create!(name: 'fabian')`

Comment: Same output, there is not changes.